# system environment variables not working

Tags: variables, cmd, system, environment

I cannot access my system environment variables from my administrative user account. I am still able to access my user environment variables though. When I try to access SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe from the Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > System > Advanced system settings, I get an error: "Windows cannot find %windir%\system32\systempropertiesadvance.exe"

From a cmd window, I entered "*echo %windir%*" and it wasn't set. After that I entered "*set*" and saw only user environment variables. I navigated to: C:\Windows\System32 and ran SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe. This worked and I saw my complete list of system variables, but I'm wondering if there is a setting I can adjust which will allow my user account access to the system variables.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\` and find `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`.
2. Start the program and click on Environment Variables button.
3. Then add new (Name: `windir`, Value: `%SystemRoot%`) to system variables.

Comment: sir you saved my 1 day. I thank you from the bottom of my heart :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I did have access, but the problem was that my user and system %PATH% variables were different. I'm not sure, but I think the user variables are used before system variables. I compared the values of user vs system and my user variable was much smaller. With this I concluded that it mush have been trying to access the wrong variable. Now I don't get the error messages anymore.